# How to send a txt file string to myself through an email?

Tags: python, email, browser-history, smtplib

I am using smtplib to send a copy of my friends history to myself, however it sends nothing to me just a plain email, anyone know what the problem is?

```
with open ("History.txt", ) as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()
data = str(data)
data = "'" + data + "'"




import smtplib
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()

server.login('myemail','mypassword')
server.sendmail('myemail', 'myotheremail', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EmailMessage` instead.

> **Python » Documentation** [email: Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#EmailMessage).
>   a few examples of how to use the email package to read, write, and send simple email messages, as well as more complex MIME messages.